# Reload all the app after upload in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, render

I'm doing a quite large app that needs to save a Javascript object and save it to client's disk and viceversa: retrieve JSON object and parse it.

I've managed to save and upload the file, but here's the problem: When the file is successfully uploaded (checked from the console and inspector), Angular does not display anything at the ng-repeats, ng-model...

I assume the problem is that Angular does not know that the object has changed. I am wondering, since I seem not to find it anywhere: **how can I re-render all of my Angular app?**

Comment: Refreshing the page should do this

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeLee ! I forgot to mention that all is client-side, so refreshing resets too the object that I want to update into my views.
I'm sure there is something in between.
Many thanks!

Comment: Just stating the obvious, but did you call `$scope.$apply()` ?

Answer (score 0):

What we did in one of our Angular projects, is some kind of 'cacheId'.

1. So imagine simple POST service generating random integer number.
2. Imagine another GET service returning that number.

Now in your Angular templates, wherever you specify template rul name, add 'cacheId' as param.

Instead oF that:

```
templateUrl: 'some-folder/some-template.tpl.html'
```

Do that:

```
templateUrl: 'some-folder/some-template.tpl.html?cachedId=' + someService.cacheId
```

What advantage?

1. You can click resetCache() url and generate different cacheId
2. client will get different cacheId in next request
3. browser will treat html template url as new url and will reload template
4. by reloading template you will get new data in

Something like that might work.